# Ember Data: create Model without store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to create a `DS.Model` object without using `store.createRecord` ?

**EDIT**

maybe I need to give some context.

I am writing an Ember Addon that has a few `model` that are not bridged through the **app/** directory and I want to write unit tests for those `model`. The auto generated unit tests uses `moduleForModel` helper which works fine if the `model` is bridged. But since my `models` are not bridged, they don't get merged to the dummy application's namespace and `moduleForModel` helper couldn't find the `model`.

This is why I wanted to be able to create `model` without using `store` object since I couldn't figure out a way to have access to `store` without using `moduleForModel` helper.

Answer (score 2):

No. `DS.Model` is an `Ember.Object`, so if it were possible, we would use `create`:

```
const User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName:   DS.attr('string'),
  lastName:    DS.attr('string'),
});

const foo = User.create({ firstName: 'Foo', lastName: 'Bar' });

> Uncaught EmberError { message: "You should not call `create` on a model. Instead, call `store.createRecord` with the attributes you would like to set.", ... ]
```

DS.Model instances are linked back to the store by design (that's how they receive updates when new data is pushed in) so it doesn't make sense to create a `DS.Model` instance without that connection. Ember Data makes this explicit by requiring you to call `createRecord` on your store instance.

Comment: This is for the context of unit testing. I added more context to my question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can push your plain javascript object (that must have appropriate keys as defined in your model definition) into the store. In terms of Ember, such object is called `hash`. Here's the [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/) for you. Be careful, after pushing your `hash` into the store, the created model will not be `new` and `dirty`. It will have state `root.loaded.saved`. More about states [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RootState.html)

Hope I helped you.